# PDO Sqlite blocking with multiple writes

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm making a simple logging class that logs messages to a sqlite database using php's pdo extension. It is logging correctly but intermittently slowly. When I load the page it logs quickly, but if a second page is loaded at nearly the same time, it sometimes hangs.

Looking at a profile from XDEBUG, it looks like the prepare and execute statements are sometimes taking very little time, but sometimes taking longer. When they are longer, they are always very close to a multiple of a second (1000, 1001 or 2001 milliseconds for example).

I've tried different combinations of using begin transaction or not and PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That is the main downside of SQLite.

**Databases have a locking mechanism** to prevent the data/schema from changing while a request is being executed. Most database servers will work in RAM then have the data persisted to disk in a threaded fashion (i.e.: write to RAM, return response, then write to disk). You must already know that writing to memory is a *gazillion* times faster than writing to disk. Since SQLite writes directly to disk, it locks the database first, writes and then free the lock. The write (to disk) part takes a lot longer than with regular database server (e.g.: MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.), causing long response times when executing multiple queries in a short delay.

The solution I've found is to **use a memory database (i.e.: `:memory:`) and dump to disk at regular intervals.** The main downside of this approach is that the data on disk is not necessarily up-to-date with the latest data (since the actual real-time data is stored in memory).

There is no magical solution, it's a root "issue" of SQLite. If you are planning to run multiple concurrent write operations on a database, **you should think about using an actual database server instead.**

Comment: I understand that writing to disk will be slower than memory, locking comes into play, and that SQLite is not as fast as other servers, but this problem is showing up with only a few writes, happening intermittently, and when it does happen is taking a very suspicious amount of time (almost exactly a multiple of a second). Because of these reasons, i think the answer is not simply that SQLite isn't fast enough. Even with each write blocking for the others, i wouldn't expect two or three writes to take (almost exactly) 1000 milliseconds.